# How to make multiple Forms Sliders in Google Colaboratory have one max across multiple sliders?

Tags: python, slider, google-colaboratory

How do I make the below sliders have a combined max of 1.0?

```
va1 = 0.1 #@param {type:"slider", min:0, max:1, step:0.1}

val2 = 0.1 #@param {type:"slider", min:0, max:1, step:0.1}

val3 = 0.1 #@param {type:"slider", min:0, max:1, step:0.1}

val4 = 0.1 #@param {type:"slider", min:0, max:1, step:0.1}

val5 = 0.1 #@param {type:"slider", min:0, max:1, step:0.1}

val6 = 0.5 #@param {type:"slider", min:0, max:1, step:0.1}
```

Currently they each have an individual max of 1.

Comment: What do you mean by combined max of 1.0?

Comment: Each val# is a percentage and the sum total of the val#'s should be 1